# Getting recent frames using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, javacv, rtsp-client, javacpp

I have a rtsp, udp multicast stream. I read frames by calling  [av_read_frame()](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#ga4fdb3084415a82e3810de6ee60e46a61) method in a loop and it works as expected. My problem is, If I sleep my loop (let's say) for 500 ms, I'm not receiving recent frames.

Since, I'm not reading a regular video file, is there any way to get recent frames ? (For e.g. which buffer should I disable or resize... I focused on ffmpeg internal buffers which may be wrong approach ?)

Comment: You could read the frames without sleeping and put them in a ring buffer and do what you need to do in another thread.

Comment: don't sleep! create a new thread if you must.

Comment: You guys (@aergistal and @szatmary)  right, actually I read the ffplay code. There is 3 separate threads, one for read, one for visualize and another  one for decoding. But CPU usage is also one of my concerns. So far, my expectancies satisfied by using %20 of CPU. I thought, flushing buffer may be a solution.

Comment: @szatmary is there no way to disable ffmpeg internal buffers? I'm using a new thread but I think I'm getting frames slower than ffmpeg fills their own buffer...